# C - iterating numberOfProducts variable does not work

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I'm new to C and am creating an online store which manages a bunch of products in its inventory. I'm having trouble printing all my products out. When the user enters '1' which should iterate through all the elements in productCollection and print out each Product object, it prints nothing.

I think it's because the numberOfProducts is always 0 even though I iterate it in addProduct(). Despite where I place the iterator, when I print the numberOfProducts, it always prints 0. I was wondering why?

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "defs.h"

void printInventory(ProductCollectionType*);
int addProduct(ProductCollectionType*, int, char*, int, float);

int main(){


    InventoryType store;
    store.storeName = "Walmart";
    
    ProductCollectionType p;
    p.numberOfProducts = 0;
    
    addProduct(&p, 1001, "Grape juice", 20, 12.5);
    addProduct(&p, 1002, "Apple juice", 30, 4.3);
    
    
    int choice;
    printf("(1) Print inventory \n");

    printf("\n");
    printf("Enter choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
  
    printf("%d \n", p.numberOfProducts);
  
    if(choice == 1){
        printInventory(&p);
    } 
    
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: In `addProduct`, `for(i = 0; i < productCollection->numberOfProducts; ++i)` is incorrect. Of course that loop never runs. `productCollection->numberOfProducts` starts as 0 and can never be incremented as the loop never runs. You don't need any loop. Just directly jump to the index you want to add into. Make sure it doesn't overflow the array.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.   the function: `addProduct()` results in the message: `untitled1.c:79:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]` This is not the only problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, function parameters are passed by value.

```
int addProduct(ProductCollectionType productCollection
```

In this function `productCollection` is **a copy** of the caller's structure.

```
productCollection.numberOfProducts++;
```

So that line modifies a local variable and not the caller's variable.

To fix, pass in a pointer insted.

```
int addProduct(ProductCollectionType *productCollection, int i, char* n, int u, float p)
{
    ...
    productCollection->numberOfProducts++;
}
```

And call as:

```
addProduct(&p, 1001, "Grape juice", 20, 12.5);
```

Comment: Hi! So I made the following changes but for some reason numberOfProducts is still printing out to be 0?

Comment: You need to make the same change everywhere - including for the `printInventory` function.

Comment: I updated my code on the post to include what my code is right now. I added a * to every function and also used arrows to access it but the problem still persists. Is it possible I'm missing something else in my code?